# MySQL DBCC CHECKIDENT syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm confused by this syntax error I keep getting when I try to execute:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('database', RESEED, 1)
```

In **PHPMyAdmin**...

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DBCC CHECKIDENT('database', RESEED, 1)' at line 1
```

The result looks like this
[image]

Comment: `DBCC CHECKIDENT('database', RESEED, 1)` is for SQL Server. Don't think it will work in MySQL.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `alter table ... auto_increment` instead. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Your right, kind new to SQL that's a stupid mistake, explains why Microsoft documented it.  Make that an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DBCC CHECKIDENT('table', RESEED, 1)` is for SQL Server.

Use `alter table ... auto_increment` instead. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
This way?